# Show loading when navigate from one view to another in react native

Tags: react-native

I am on React native 0.29 for android. I used navigator in my app so that user can navigate from one view to another. I want to know is there any way I can show a loading symbol when navigator is navigating from one view to another.

Comment: Navigation should not be so slow that you need an loading symbol for that. Could be a performance issue. My suggestion would be to investigate that instead of adding a loading indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the reason you're navigation is delayed is because you're fetching data asynchronously to prepare the next view. This answer isn't going to be very helpful if you've just got a performance concern.

Anyway, I've followed this basic pattern, basically I set the loader to true, then after I have the data, I set the loader to false and pass the data along to the view as a prop.

```
_handleLogin() {
    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
    },
    () => 
      Api.getUser( username, password )
        .then( user => this._handleResponse( user ))
    );
  }

  _handleResponse( user ){
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
    })

    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      passProps: {
        user: user,
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am using the same approach in listview. I have a view with webview component inside it. So it is taking time to display. For that view I am asking for the loader.

Comment: You might also try the container pattern. https://voice.kadira.io/stubbing-react-containers-for-testing-11bcd537e586#.u344y8isi

Comment: Thanks. I will try.